# Power of the integral of a Geometric Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm struggling to say anything about the following random variable:

$$\Bigg(\int_0^\infty e^{aB_t-bt}dt\Bigg)^\eta  \;\;\;(1)$$

where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion, $b>0$ and $\eta\in\mathbb{R}$. I found a result in Yor (*Exponential functionals of Brownian Motion and related processes*, 2001) which indicates that

$$\int_0^\infty e^{aB_t-bt}dt$$

where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion and $b>0$ is distributed as the reciprocal of a gamma variable (up to a multiplicative constant).

I'd like to go further, at least computing the mean of (1) if possible. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but assuming that you can find the shape and scale parameter of the aforementioned gamma distributed random variable, i.e
$$
X = \int_0^\infty e^{aB_t-bt}dt \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} Y^{-1},
$$
where $Y\sim \Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ for some shape parameter $\alpha>0$ and scale parameter $\beta>0$ then $X$ is [inverse gamma distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) with shape parameter $\alpha$ and scale parameter $\beta$. Thus

\begin{align*}
E(X^\eta) &= \int_0^\infty x^\eta \frac{ \beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{-\alpha-1} \exp\left( -\frac{\beta}{x} \right) dx \\
 &= \frac{ \beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-\eta) }{\beta^{\alpha-\eta}} \int_0^\infty \frac{ \beta^{\alpha-\eta}}{\Gamma(\alpha-\eta)} x^{-(\alpha-\eta)-1} \exp\left( -\frac{\beta}{x} \right) dx \\
 &= \frac{ \beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-\eta) }{\beta^{\alpha-\eta}} ,
\end{align*} 
if $\alpha> \eta$.